# Concat DataFrame to multi index df keeping original multi index

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation, multi-index

I have 2 dataframes from a budgeting finances project, one df of the recorded spending;

```
                          Food  Clothes  Bills  Social  Travel  Art  Other  Daily Total
Week End   Today's Date
2020-09-27 2020-09-21     25       25     25      25      25   25     25          175
           2020-09-23     20       20     20      20      20   20     20          140
           2020-09-24     12       12     12      12      12   12     12           84
           2020-09-25     20       20     20      20      20   20     20          140
```

And one of the weekly total's;

```
     Food  Clothes  Bills  Social  Travel  Art  Other  Daily Total
0    77       77     77      77      77   77     77          539
```

I'd like to concat them whilst keeping the original multi index to look like this;

```
                          Food  Clothes  Bills  Social  Travel  Art  Other  Daily Total
Week End   Today's Date
2020-09-27 2020-09-21     25       25     25      25      25   25     25          175
           2020-09-23     20       20     20      20      20   20     20          140
           2020-09-24     12       12     12      12      12   12     12           84
           2020-09-25     20       20     20      20      20   20     20          140
                0         77       77     77      77      77   77     77          539
```

If I do a basic concat function the multi index turns into a bunch of tuples like;

```
                                              Food  Clothes  Bills  Social

(2020-09-27 00:00:00, 2020-09-21 00:00:00)     25       25     25      25 
etc.
```

Any ideas?? Fairly new to pandas and coding in general so any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the column titles to make them easier to work with.
Week End = Week_End
Today's Date = Todays_Date
Daily_Total

You can just append the row

df2 contains your weekly totals

```
#set an index to match your recorded spending df
df2['Week_End'] = '2020-09-27'
df2['Todays_Date'] = '0'
df2.set_index(['Week_End', 'Todays_Date'], inplace=True)


#append df2 to df
df = df.append(df2)
```

results in:

```
                        Food  Clothes  Bills  Social  Travel  Art  Other  Daily_Total
Week_End   Todays_Date                                                               
2020-09-27 2020-09-21     25       25     25      25      25   25     25          175
           2020-09-23     20       20     20      20      20   20     20          140
           2020-09-24     12       12     12      12      12   12     12           84
           2020-09-25     20       20     20      20      20   20     20          140
           0              77       77     77      77      77   77     77          539
```

Comment: Ah pretty simple, I was thinking I would have to remove the index from the first df then add it back on afterwards, cheers!